# Is the instance variable of Akka Actor thread-safe?

Tags: scala, akka

I want to calculate the input and output of the actors in my system.
There will be a `StatActor`, when it gets a message, it will plus the instance variable.
I want to know, is it thread-safe? I ran the prototype code several times, it was always OK.
Do i need to use `volatile` or `AtomicLong` etc?

The prototype code :

```
object VariableCountTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sys = ActorSystem()
    val stat = sys.actorOf(Props[Stat], "stat")
    val b = sys.actorOf(Props(classOf[Sender], stat), "b")
    val a = sys.actorOf(Props(classOf[Sender], stat), "a") //Two senders

    for (i <- 1 to 1000*1000*100) {
      if(i%3==0){
        b ! Stat.start
      }else{
        a ! Stat.start
      }
    }
  }

}



object Stat{
  case object stat;
  case object start;
  case object result;
}

class Stat extends Actor  with ActorLogging{

  var stat = 0L

  def receive = {
    case Stat.stat =>
      if(stat%100000==0){
        log.info("**"+stat)
      }
       stat = stat+1;
    case Stat.result =>
       sender() ! stat
  }

}



class Sender(target: ActorRef) extends Actor  with ActorLogging{

  def receive = {
    case Stat.start =>
      target ! Stat.stat
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the whole point of the Actor Model :-) I recommend reading for example the [general section](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/actors.html#state) or the section on the [memory model](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/jmm.html) in the documentation.

Comment: The memory model part says :"We recommend not to close over non-final fields (final in Java and val in Scala), and if you do choose to close over non-final fields, they must be marked volatile in order for the current value of the field to be visible to the callback."  So the field `stat` should be marked volatile, am i right?

Comment: No, that only talks about accessing the fields from functions (closures) that are called from outside the actor, like Futures.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the volatile or AtomicLong in the same actor instance. It is by sequence.

Remember:

1. One actor is by sequence.
2. Concurrency is the multiple actor's behavior.